# How to debug native code in an Android library project?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am developing an Android library with native code. This library project is added as a library in an application project.

I would like to debug the library when the application project is using it.

I am pretty sure the settings in the library (makefiles, build command, compiler options) project are ok because I tried the debugger from within the library (I created a dummy Activity and unset "library") and it worked. I am also aware of the delay that might occur because of the time needed to load the dynamic library and I don't think it's the issue for the same reason.

In the Application project, I just added native code support set the build command as `ndk_build NDK_DEBUG=1`, **but it never stops at breakpoints**. Any idea would be greatly appreciated

Comment: are you debugging with gdb? You cannot debug with the normal eclipse debugger. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10534367/how-to-get-ndk-gdb-working-on-android

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try the answer by Jay in my question: [debug native code in Android library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12638849/debug-native-code-in-android-library).
I had no time to test it by my self, but it looks promising.
Let me know if it works.

Comment: How it works for you? When I create new "Android Native Application" debug configuration and choose "Browse" for project, the application project nor the library project (that with native code) is shown on the list.