# using gdb for android from a linux terminal

Tags: android, debugging, terminal

I have a C++ program for android that I would like to debug by running line by line (stepping through) in the same way I can using gdb on Linux from terminal and have it also print out all the current variables and their values at each step. Is this possible and how would I accomplish this? Please note the c++ program is not built from any IDE, just using terminal commands. I see a lot of stuff listed such as ndk-gdb, but I'm not really sure where to start.

Comment: Have you looked at this?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10534367/how-to-get-ndk-gdb-working-on-android

Answer (score 2):

Try the instructions listed in this [manual](http://www.kandroid.org/online-pdk/guide/debugging_gdb.html). They seem to be aimed towards command line usage.

Update: Since kandroid.org has removed information about debugging with gdb, I dug up [this](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/wiki/Android-debugging-with-remote-GDB) piece instead. Hopefully it will stick around longer.