# Debugging an ARM assembly (Neon extension)

Tags: debugging, assembly, android-ndk, arm

I am developing an algorithm that uses ARM Neon instructions. I am writing the code using assembler file (`.S` and no inline asm).

My question is that what is the best way for debugging purpose i.e. viewing registers, memory, etc.
Currently, I am using `Android NDK` to compile and my Android phone to run the algorithm.

Comment: The best and only way to single step ARM code and see NEON registers is using Visual Studio from Microsoft  with a Surface RT (or 2) over WIFI to a Windows PC.

Comment: For simple assembly blocks you might try [NEVADA](http://szeged.github.io/nevada/), but you'll have to set up your test conditions manually, rather than testing it in-place within your application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Poor man's debug solutions...

You can use `gdb` / `gdbserver` to remotely control execution of applications on an Android phone. I'm not giving full details here because they change all the time but for example you can start with this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10539883/1163019) or make a quick search on Internet. Learning to use GDB might seem to have a high steep curve however material on web is exhaustive. You can easily find something to your taste.

Single-stepping an ARM core via software tools is hard that's why ARM ecosystem is full of expensive tools and extra HW equipment.

Trick I use is to insert `BRK` instructions manually in assembly code. BRK is *Self-hosted debug breakpoint.* When core sees this instruction it stops and informs OS about situation. OS then notifies debugger about the situation and passes control to it. When debugger gets control you can check contents of registers and probably even make changes to them. Last part of the operation is to make your process continue. Since `PC` is still at our break point instruction what you must do is to increase `PC`, set it to instruction after `BRK`.

Since you mentioned you use `.S` files instead of `.s` files you can utilize `gcc` to do preprocessing / macro work. This way enabling, disabling `BRK` might become less of an issue.

Big down side of this way of working is turnaround time. If there is a certain point that you want to investigate with gdb you must make sure there is a `BRK` instruction there and this will probably require another build/push/debug cycle.

Comment: Thank you @auselen . Can you elaborate the difference between `.S` and `.s`? What do you mean by preprocessing? In C?

Comment: The difference between `.S` and `.s` is that the `.S` files are intended to be preprocessed by `cpp`, the C preprocessor. It handles things like `#define`s, `#ifdef`s. etc. See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html for official comment.