# Replacing JNI Crashes by Exceptions on Android

Tags: java, android, c, android-ndk, signals

I have developed an Android application that uses a native C library. I could successfully compile the whole thing using JNI, and everything works smoothly.

However, every now and then the native C library crashes (most frequently with a SIGSEGV). This, in turn, causes my application to crash without any meaningful notice for the user. What I would like to achieve is the following:

1. Catch the signal in the native code using a signal handler (sigaction) to prevent random crashes
2. Throw an exception in the C library that Java can catch
3. Catch the exception in Java, generate a meaningful warning message for the user and keep the app running

In case that this is of any use for you - the JNI code runs in a separate thread (to be more precise inside an AsyncTask).

I already checked http://blog.httrack.com/blog/2013/08/23/catching-posix-signals-on-android/ and https://github.com/xroche/coffeecatch
but I cannot get it to compile.

Following the suggestions from [Best way to throw exceptions in JNI code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230689/best-way-to-throw-exceptions-in-jni-code) and [How to catch JNI Crashes as exceptions using Signal handling based mechanism in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30105719/how-to-catch-jni-crashes-as-exceptions-using-signal-handling-based-mechanism-in) and https://www.developer.com/java/data/exception-handling-in-jni.html
I carried out the following steps:

In my native code I added the following function that (to my understanding) sets up a signal handler:

```
void initializeSignalHandler(JNIEnv* env){
    int watched_signals[] = { SIGABRT, SIGILL, SIGSEGV, SIGINT, SIGKILL }; // 6, 4, 11, 2, 9
    struct sigaction sighandler;
    memset(&sighandler, 0, sizeof(sighandler));

    sighandler.sa_sigaction = &sighandler_func;
    sighandler.sa_mask = 0;
    sighandler.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO | SA_ONSTACK;
    for(int ii=0; ii<5; ii++){
        int signal = watched_signals[ii];
        sigaction(signal, &sighandler, NULL);        
    }
    env = env;
}
```

My function that handles these signals looks like this:

```
void sighandler_func(int sig, siginfo_t* sig_info, void* ptr){
    printerr("Sighandler: ", sig);
    jclass jcls = (*env)->FindClass(env, "java/lang/Error");
    jboolean flag = (*env)->ExceptionCheck(env);
    if (flag) {
        (*env)->ExceptionClear(env);
        /* code to handle exception */
    }
    if (jcls!=NULL){
        printerr("Throwing exception");
        (*env)->ThrowNew(env, jcls, "error message");
    }
}
```

My critical JNI function begins by configuring the signal handler:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_android_playground_criticalFuction
    (JNIEnv *env, jclass c, jlong handle, jshortArray out_buffer){


    // new signal handler
    struct sigaction sighandler;
    initializeSignalHandler(env);

    // ...here goes the critical code
}
```

When a SIGILL occurs in my native C code the following happens:

1) On my debug terminal I get the following four messages

- Sighandler: 4 (that corresponds to SIGILL)
- Throwing exception
- Sighandler: 4
- Sighandler: 11

2) The app window closes but I do not get the Android message 
      "Unfortunately ... was closed" that usually appears when an app crashes

I do not really understand why I get the third and fourth signal message as I would  assume that the exception is thrown. In addition, I think that the exception is never really thrown (to Java).

I am lost and any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What you can do in a signal handler is fairly restricted. For example, using dynamic memory allocation in a signal handler (`ThrowNew` sounds like it will try to allocate some memory) is considered undefined behavior in C++. I know this is C, but there's a good chance similar restrictions apply there.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/34553070/1524450 for additional info.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if what you are trying to do here is technically possible.  @Michael's comments imply that it isn't possible.

But if it is possible, it is a bad idea.

By the time the native code you are using has triggered a SIGSEGV, it could have done untold damage; e.g. overwriting objects in the heap, etcetera.  If you attempt to recover, there is a significant chance that the damage *that has already occurred* will lead to unexpected behavior or incorrect results.  Worse still, it could cause the application to lock up or the GC to crash some time (maybe hours) later due to heap corruption, stuck threads, etcetera.

This is why it is standard behavior for a JVM to panic when an unexpected SIGSEGV occurs in native code OR in Java code.  And why JVMs provide no way to suppress these panics.

While it is nice to give the users a meaningful error, there is not much meaningful that you can tell them if you are getting random SIGSEGV errors and other JVM panics.  You should focus on fixing the cause of the panics.