# Debugging C/C++ code of an Android Native APK

Tags: android, visual-studio-code, apk, vscode-debugger, vscode-remote

I have built a set of headless Vulkan applications that I can compile for various platforms {Win/Mac/Android} and run as native executables. For reasons related mostly to RenderDoc capture and debugging, I need to be able to build and deploy these applications as APKs. Following a method similar to https://github.com/cnlohr/rawdrawandroid, I scripted the necessary signing and packaging as part of my build system and used the android_native_app_glue to minimally connect to the existing code. Now I have an APK with zero Java code, which I am now trying to figure out how to conveniently connect to a debugger. https://github.com/adelphes/android-dev-ext is not an option because this is apparently only suitable for Java code. I’ve previously had success with a remote-lldb configuration in my launch.json (shown below), but I haven’t been able to figure out a similar solution for an APK.

Is it is possible to create a configuration that allows remote debugging of an APK? It seems like all the ingredients are available but I’ve not been able to find an example of this being done. It appears possible to remotely connect to a running APK as in https://www.sh-zam.com/2019/05/debugging-krita-on-android.html, but I haven’t figured out how to reproduce this functionality in a launch.json config.

```
    {
        "name"           : "Remote Debug",
        "type"           : "lldb",
        "request"        : "launch",
        "program"        : "${workspaceFolder}/bin/testApp", // Local path, will be copied to device automatically
        "breakpointMode" : "path",
        "initCommands"   : [
            "platform select remote-android",
            "platform connect connect://e9646fd7:10086",
            "settings set target.inherit-env false", // don't want to inherit host machine environment
        ],
}
```

Comment: Do you have `android:debuggable="true"` flag in the `AndroidManifest.xml`? have you seen this article: https://enes-ozturk.medium.com/remote-debugging-with-gdb-b4b0ca45b8c1 hope you can find it useful

Comment: Yes, I have android:debuggable="true" flag in AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

I believe these two links should provide the answers you need:

- [Android Developers: ndk-gdb](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/ndk-gdb)
- [How to get ndk-gdb working on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10534367/how-to-get-ndk-gdb-working-on-android)

Basically, it boils down to running a remote `gdb` debugging session using [gdbserver](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb/html_node/gdb_130.html) on the Android side, as described on the links above.  Once the remote session is established, it should behave very similarly to any other debugging session for a native application.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I think those are a bit out of date, this page (https://source.android.com/docs/core/tests/debug/gdb) states that gdb is no longer supported. And I'm interested in how to make a debugging session interact cleanly with VSCode.

Comment: Huh, I'm afraid I can't help with VSCode, because I don't use it.