# My app crashes in Play Console (signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR))

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-2.0.0, google-play-console, cordova-8.0.0

Android app (hybrid app built on cordova) recorded more crashes in Google Play Console, signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR). crash happening only in production app

```
pid: 0, tid: 0 >>> My App package name <<<
backtrace:


  #00  pc 000000000147a832  /data/app/com.android.chrome-HY_VMhbJ0-Nzo6iNC_o1EA==/base.apk

#01  pc 0000000000000000  <unknown>
```

I had checked below links also but no use

[android Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x9 in tid 27173](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47234991/android-fatal-signal-11-sigsegv-code-1-fault-addr-0x9-in-tid-27173)

[signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9975675/signal-11-sigsegv-code-1-segv-maperr)

This issue is happening only in Android 8.0 and above OS, how do i fix this crash

Comment: The issue is fixed in latest chrome update 87

Comment: Hi, i bumped in similar problem. How you solved it?